# Cannot solve this algebraic equation in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

Hello i am trying to solve a algebric equation in maxima, the equation has alpha, delta and psi as variable. I want the alpha in equation to be solved in terms of psi and delta. I tried using the solve command but i am getting alpha in terms of alpha.

Here is the equation to solve Equation to solve

[image]

And this is the output from maxima

[image].

This is the code i am trying -->

```
solve([(sqrt(-4*alpha*delta*psi-4*delta*psi+alpha^2*delta^2)/(delta^2+delta)-(alpha*delta/(delta^2+delta)))/2-sqrt(4*alpha^2*delta^2+6*alpha*delta^2+3*delta^2+2*alpha^2*delta+4*alpha*delta+2*delta)/(3*delta^2+2*delta)+alpha*delta/(3*delta^2+2*delta)=0],alpha);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with that algebraic equation is that involves square roots,or radicals and normal polynomial, and that that type of equation is not easy to solve, take a look at this equation:

```
(%i30) solve(x=sqrt(x+6),x);

(%o30) x = sqrt{x+6}
```

So Maxima doesn't return any value, but for example other software Mathematica does.
Let's square both sides of equation and try to solve it

```
(%i31) solve(x^2=x+6,x);

(%o31) x=3 , x=-2
```

we get two solutions, let's try with first equation:

```
3 = sqrt(3+6) => 3 = sqrt(9) => 3 = 3

-2 = sqrt(-2+6) => -2 = sqrt(4) => -2 = 2 ??????
```

So the second solution is not valid,

> maxima solve program in Macsyma/Maxima generally avoids methods that
> produce false solutions,  like "square both sides".   It may still
> make errors based on dividing by expressions that appear to be
> non-zero, but actually ARE zero,  and maybe some other similar
> situations.

from this [mailing list](http://def.fe.up.pt/pipermail/maxima-discuss/2015/050448.html)

In your case I will factor the equation to get a simplified version but with those free variable this will be difficult so, try to assume some values for psi and delta:

```
(%i26) solve(factor((sqrt(-4*alpha*delta*psi-4*delta*psi+alpha^2*delta^2)/(delta^2+delta)-(alpha*delta/(delta^2+delta)))/2-sqrt(4*alpha^2*delta^2+6*alpha*delta^2+3*delta^2+2*alpha^2*delta+4*alpha*delta+2*delta)/(3*delta^2+2*delta)+alpha*delta/(3*delta^2+2*delta))=0,alpha);

(\%o26) \left[ \alpha=\ifrac{\left(3\,\delta+2\right)\,\isqrt{\left(-4\,\alpha-4\right)\,\delta\,\psi+\alpha^2\,\delta^2}+\left(-2\,\delta-2\right)\,\isqrt{\left(4\,\alpha^2+6\,\alpha+3\right)\,\delta^2+\left(2\,\alpha^2+4\,\alpha+2\right)\,\delta}}{\delta^2} \right]
```

Expand your Equation and try to remove square roots or some assumptions:

```
Equation : (sqrt(-4*alpha*delta*psi-4*delta*psi+alpha^2*delta^2)/(delta^2+delta)-(alpha*delta/(delta^2+delta)))/2-sqrt(4*alpha^2*delta^2+6*alpha*delta^2+3*delta^2+2*alpha^2*delta+4*alpha*delta+2*delta)/(3*delta^2+2*delta)+alpha*delta/(3*delta^2+2*delta);
```

Comment: If this helped you, please consider to upvote or validate the answer, thanks

Comment: You say "let's square both sides of an equation" and proceed to show how to TYPE the squared equation into Maxima. A more useful advice would be to explain how to TELL Maxima to square both sides of an equation.